# What is the most Reliable way to find the X Path / CSS of the Gmail Compose Button?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

within the code Below the comment -- "click on compose button" there are 3 different ways i tried to locate the compose button.All of three ways works fine at once , but later none of them worked , Why ?
    i am not able to get the attribute - changing dynamically ?

```
    package selenium;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    public class Gmail {
    static String Email="xyz@gmail.com";
    static String psw="klj";


        public static void main(String[] s) throws InterruptedException
        {
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

             driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");

             // Entering Text Into the Email field 
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys(Email);
             // click on the Next  Button 

             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();

             try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             // Entering text into the password Field 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*  

    [@id='gaia_loginform']//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(psw);          

            // click on the sign in Button
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*     

    [@id='gaia_loginform']//div/input[@id='signIn']")).click();

            //maximize the window 
            driver.manage().window().maximize();


           try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // clicking  on Compose Button  via 3 different ways 

     // un-comment below statement and run 
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();

    // Or Run Via below statement      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='z0']/div[@role='button']")).click();  


    // Or Using CSS Selector 
        //WebElement composeBtn 
  =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']"));
           //composeBtn.click();
            //System.out.println("Passed");

            driver.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what the xpath should be ("find the xpath"), or are you trying to _use_ the xpath to find the button? The words you used are a bit confusing.

Comment: @Bryan  :I  have to figure Out the x path to pick the Compose button every time i run the code : Actually when i run the code it doesn't picks the compose button as it does the first time

Comment: "Don't automate Google's products" @ http://yizeng.me/2014/07/19/why-you-shouldnt-start-learning-selenium-by-automating-googles-products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class changes, find something else about the element that is unique. For example, it appears to be the only button on the page with the word "COMPOSE", so something like this should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'COMPOSE')][@role='button']"))
```

Comment: Bryan: what does dot means  in [contains(. , 'COMPOSE')]  ?         as we could use [contains(@text(),'COMPOSE' )]          i tried with double dots it was highlighting lot many elements.

Comment: The dot means "the current node". Two dots means "the parent node". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Axis_specifiers